# Ventana que te pregunte si quiero eliminar el registro

Tags: php, html, css

quiero crear un pop up o algo parecido que pregunte si deseo eliminar el registro,para eliminar un registro uso un botón que utilizada el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
   include('../../lang/lang_config.php');
   include('../config/aplicar.php');

   if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']))
   {
       $id= $_GET['id'];
       $page = $_GET['page'];
       $tbl_name = 'tbl_'.$page;
       $where = "id = 'id'";
       $where = "id = '$id'";

       

       $query = $obj->delete_data($tbl_name,$where);
       $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);

       if($res == true)
       {
           $_SESSION['borrar'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['borrar_bien']."</div>";
           header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page='.$page);
       }
       else
       {
           $_SESSION['borrar'] = "<div class='error'>".$lang['borra_mal']."</div>";
           header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page='.$page);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/');
   }
```

No se como lo podría hacer para que saliese en la misma página o como podría para hacer el pop up.
EDITO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código seria:

```
<div class="body">
   <h2><?php echo $lang['autores'] ?></h2>
   <br>
   <?php 
       if(isset($_SESSION['aña']))
       {
           echo $_SESSION['aña'];
           unset($_SESSION['aña']);
       }
       if(isset($_SESSION['edit']))
       {
           echo $_SESSION['edit'];
           unset($_SESSION['edit']);
       }
       if(isset($_SESSION['borrar']))
       {
           echo $_SESSION['borrar'];
           unset($_SESSION['borrar']);
       }
   ?>
   <table class="tbl-responsive">
       <tr>
           <td colspan="5">
               <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/index.php?page=add_autor"><button class="btn-primary btn-sm"><?php echo $lang['aña'] ?></button></a>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th><?php echo $lang['sn'] ?></th>
           <th><?php echo $lang['nombre'] ?></th>
           
           <th><?php echo $lang['acciones'] ?></th>
       </tr>

       <?php 
           $tbl_name = 'tbl_autor';
           $query = $obj->select_data($tbl_name);
           $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
           $sn = 1;

           if($res==true)
           {
               $count_rows = $obj->num_rows($res);
               if($count_rows>0)
               {
                   while ($row=$obj->fetch_data($res)) {
                       $id = $row['id'];
                       $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                       
                       ?>
                       <tr>
                           <td><?php echo $sn++; ?>. </td>
                           <td><?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?></td>
                           
                           <td>
                               <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/index.php?page=edit_autor&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-success btn-sm"><?php echo $lang['edit'] ?></a> 
                               <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/pages/delete.php?page=autor&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-error btn-sm"><?php echo $lang['borrar'] ?></a>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   echo"<tr><td colspan='5' class='error'>".$lang['noautor']."</td></tr>";
               }
           }
       ?>
       
   </table>
</div>
```

Tengo varias páginas y siempre esta el botón de borrar, al darle elimina el registro automáticamente , sin preguntar no se si tendría que modificar el borrar.php o crar una nueva página que sería para enseñar el pop up y en caso de darle a SI que ejecute borrar.php.

Comment: Eso debe ser en la vista donde tengas los registros a eliminar para saber como puedes enviar el mensaje. Agrega el código de esa vista para darte algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega la funcionalidad que utilizo con bootstrap y jquery, adaptado a tu url de eliminación

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                
    $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">                          

<a href="#" data-href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/pages/delete.php?page=autor&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" target="#exampleModal"> Eliminar</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alerta</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      ¿Desea eliminar el registro?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Eliminar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo completo https://codigosdeprogramacion.com/2017/01/06/curso-en-php-y-mysql-4-crud-parte-2/

Comment: Pues es verdad que podría hacerlo así , pensaba que tendría que hacer algo como un pop up que difumine el resto de la página.

Comment: @Agat0 ya actualice la respuesta, ejecuta el código y mira como funciona

Comment: ¿El primer código que seria?

Comment: @Agat0 lo primero es javascript para que al presionar el botón de eliminar (el que aparece en el modal) redireccione a tu script donde eliminas el registro

Comment: ok, luego lo adaptaré a mi css,y la url pondré la página donde se encuentra al borrar.

Comment: Al parecer si le cambias el CSS deja de funcionar correctamente ya que el modal no se oculta.

Comment: @Agat0 es correcto ya que el modal es de bootstrap y necesita sus bibliotecas para funcionar correctamente

Comment: Entonces no me sirve , ya que me cambia todo el estilo que tengo , porque al ponerlo me lo cambia entero tanto de la tabla como el de los botones.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la librería SweetAler2 te pongo un código de ejemplo queuso yo. Lo bueno que tiene la librería es que es totalmente personalizable y en el ejemplo que te puse yo si o si tenes que hacer click en un opción por mas que hagas click afuera del cuadro no sirve.

```js
$(".eliminar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    Swal.fire({
        iconHtml: '!',
        iconColor: '#c852e5',
        title: '<span style="color:#FFF; font-size: 25px;">Desea eliminar el dispositivo?</span>',
        background:'#27293D',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        stopKeydownPropagation: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#c852e5',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, Eliminar'
    }).then((result) => {
         if (result.isConfirmed) {
         Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            iconColor:'#c852e5',
            title: '<span style="color:#FFF; font-size: 25px;">Borrado!</span>',
            html: '<span style="color:#FFF;">Su dispositivo fue borrado!</span>',
            confirmButtonText: 'Salir',
            confirmButtonColor: '#c852e5',
            background:'#27293D',
         }).then(function() {
            window.location = "/app/devices.php?pagina=1&eliminar="+id;
        });
         }
     })      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
<button id="<?php echo $valor['id'];>"class="eliminar">
Borrar                                                     </button>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.11/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```